# Intercept browser request using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on google chrome extension which get the page url and analyze it. How can i `intercept` the browser `request` and serve that request condionally based on some `criteria`. I'm surfing but could find any material.

Answer (score 2):

That's going to be very tricky, if at all possible.

The closest that extensions API provide is blocking [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). There, you can intercept a request and make a decision to allow it or block it, but..

1. You can only do that until the request is sent out. So you can only rely on the URL and maybe request headers. Even in later events (when it's too late to redirect) no point `webRequest` API gives access to the response itself.
2. You have to make the decision *synchronously*, which basically severely limits processing options.

What you could do (very much in theory) is always redirect the request to your own "loading" page, meanwhile trying to replicate the request yourself (near-impossible to fully do, also consider side-effects), analyze the response and then substitute the "loading" page with the real one.

It's going to be either very complicated or impossible to do in complex cases. You're basically trying to implement an intercepting proxy in a Chrome extension - it doesn't really provide the full toolset to do so.

Comment: Atleast this give me an idea. Thanks.